# How to connect my Linux netbook (BCM4313) and Windows XP (Ralink USB) wirelessly?

Tags: linux, windows-xp, wireless-networking, drivers, hostapd

BCM4313 is handled only by staging brcm80211, Windows XP cannot into master mode.

Master mode on netbook (with brcm80211 driver) don't work: hostapd can't start, airbase-ng works only in one direction (can't receive) and easily panics the kernel. And it is said that bcrm80211 works only in managed mode now.

On the other side, Windows XP can only managed and ad-hoc.

Currently using Ralink USB inside virtual machine with debian which sets it to master mode, but this is unstable: without [speed limiting](https://github.com/vi/tcplim) it hangs soon, with limit it hangs after several hours of usage.

How to connect them reliably without additional devices?

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're attempting - are you trying to capture the data transferred between the two devices?

Comment: No, just connecting them. There's no third device.

Comment: Maybe you should use bluetooth networking using Blueman or NetworkManager ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Broadcom's proprietary "wl.ko" driver to get it into Ad-hoc mode.